# Namespacing with polymorphic relationships Laravel 5

Tags: namespaces, polymorphism, laravel-5

Upgraded to L5 and loving it! However currently facing an issue with polymorphing a relationship. In my *userable* column in the *Users* table **I need to include the namespaced value (e.g. "App\Employee" rather than just "Employee")** for the polymorph relationship to work.

Feels like I am missing something.. **How do I avoid forcing to store namespaced values in the table?** :)

PS: Well aware others are struggling with similar issues (e.g. [Laravel 5 namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376462/laravel-5-namespaces)) but have not seen anything relating to avoiding to store the namespacing in the tables..

**BaseController**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Client;
use App\User;
...
```

**HomeController**

```
$user = User::with('userable')->get();

foreach ($user as $u){
    var_dump($u->userable->mobile);
}
```

**User model**

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Client model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

**Employee model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a separate column in the *User* table. One for *role* (e.g. Admin, Employee etc.) and another column for the *userable_type* (e.g. '\App\Admin')

```
protected $morphClass
```

Seemed promising
 ([Polymorphic Eloquent relationships with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881963/polymorphic-eloquent-relationships-with-namespaces?rq=1)) but has known bugs in the inversed relationship ([Laravel 5 namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376462/laravel-5-namespaces))

And even the latter does not work quite elegantly - so until it is resolved, I'll go for the two column approach - hopes this helps others!